# MAC OS - How to install MongoDB via an AppleScript?

Tags: macos, mongodb, automation, applescript

The following link describes how to install [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community) automatically and manually in MAC OS,

http://www.bigspaceship.com/mongodb-on-mac/

This can be automatically installed via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). The following commands needs to be given one by one in system shell,

```
brew update
brew install mongodb
```

Can the whole process be done via an AppleScript automatically? If yes, what is the code for it?

After passing the command `brew update` it needs to wait until the Homebrew is updated before moving onto the next command. Also wait until the `brew install mongodb` has installed MongoDB before completing the AppleScript.

Comment: This smells of an XY-question. You're better off installing HomeBrew, then you can just run "brew install mongodb" to get MongoDB installed.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please read it again.

Comment: Why would you do that using Applescript - just use `bash`.

Comment: I have a program which requires MongoDB installed. I need to give my clients who are not computer savvy, the program and MongoDB. They needs to have everything installed automatically with one double-click. They run the AppleScript and everything is installed. This is why I need AppleScript.

Comment: Ok, how about `do shell script "brew update; brew install mongodb"`

Comment: Great idea. Thanks. Can you also look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102285/mac-os-how-to-install-mongodb-via-an-applescript-part-2)?